# Port Scanner Challenge with Python

Tags: python, port

I am doing a class with "violent_python", and the task is to loop through a list of ports until you find the one that matches the port the challenge wants you to find.

Here is the code that works when taking user input of a port number to give back a banner for the port that is given.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.settimeout(2)

print("Enter Port Number:")

port = int( raw_input() )           #used raw_input to take user input and convert it into "string" variable to accept letters and numbers

try:
    s.connect(("ad.samsclass.info", port))          #port variable parameter tells program to put user input stored in "port" variable above as the port to connect to
    print s.recv(1024)
    s.close()

except socket.error as err:
    print err
```

Now my task is to take this and enumerate it on it to loop through ports 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, and so on until it returns the banner from the hidden desired port. 
I need to make a loop to loop through a list of integers until it finds the one that returns the hidden CTF so to speak. Using the code above as a base.

I have already found out that the port is 3000 because I just added 3000 into the code I already made that is posted above. However, I do want to know how to do that without guessing for obvious reasons. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a loop and looping over a `range` of ports?

Comment: I have that's exactly what I wrote in the above posted statement......... I'm saying I don't know the structure with how to do it

Comment: Is there any reason for using Python 2?

Comment: I am not using Python 2